# Can I use mdb vue (Material Design Vue) along side with Bootstrap Vue ? What are the risks?

Tags: c#, vue.js, model-view-controller, bootstrap-vue, material-design-bootstrap

I'm currently using Bootstrap v4.3.1 and Bootstrap Vue 2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do, but you will find a **lot of issues** such as:

1. **Different design systems**, your UI will look weird and the elements will not show consistency.
2. Some CSS properties will be **overwritten** between both libraries and components will show erratic behaviors.
3. More libraries mean that your users need to **load more resources** from your server, so the rendering time will be increased for things that with one library would be enough.

My advice, don't do it, save a lot of pain and pick one, if you need to customize styles you can try with tailwind.css that play wells with both libraries that you're mentioning.

Comment: its a matter of what loads first then. I'll probably stick to just 1 css library for a fast server respond. tnx

Answer (score 0):

You're loading more than you need to into your app. When you add Bootstrap Vue, the Bootstrap library is loaded along with it plus some additional contents specifically for Vue. Bootstrap-Vue requires the Bootstrap library to be added to your packages, but only `Vue.use(BootstrapVue)` (or whatever you import it as) is required.

Take a look at the documentation here: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs

As for the risks, if you ever decide to re-write some themes or material designs, you could run into overwriting issues. At the least you're bloating your Vue.

Comment: so its not possible because of style conflicts ?

Comment: They are the same thing. App.use only Bootstrap-Vue.